# vimtutor not working as expected - how to fix?

Tags: linux-debian

### Background

I've been using Linux for years now and my daily driver is Debian Jessie. I have been using vim for about 2 years but my vim skills are sub-optimal (I still really only use the basics).

I've decided that I want to improve my vim usage and I recently read a suggestion that before you start with anything too advanced, get to know the vimtutor inside out (complete it daily for at least a week).

However vim tutor doesn't work. I recall this issue when I first started with vim and just manually copied the tutor file. My guess is that it's to do with something I "configured" before I knew what I was doing. But I'd like to fix it now if I'm going to be doing it daily.

### The Problem

Here's the error I get (within vim) when I run `vimtutor`:

```
"$VIMRUNTIME/tutor/tutor.vim" [New DIRECTORY]
Error detected while processing command line:
E471: Argument required
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Pressing enter just leaves me editing an empty file. If I try to quit out of that (`:q`) I get:

```
"nocp" [New File]
--- Options ---
noloadplugins         scroll=16
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Again enter leaves me in an empty file. Quit again gives me:

```
E173: 1 more file to edit
```

And quit a 3rd time takes me back to the command line...!?

### What I've tried:

- checking out ln 471 of `/usr/share/vim/vim74/tutor/tutor.vim`:
  only goes to line 200 so the offending line must be somewhere else?!
- reinstalling vim & vim-gtk (`apt-get install --reinstall vim vim-gtk`)
- purging `vim-tiny` (it wasn't installed).

### Further info

The last few lines of the vimtutor script (`/usr/bin/vimtutor`) are:

```
# Use Vim to copy the tutor, it knows the value of $VIMRUNTIME
# The script tutor.vim tells Vim which file to copy
$VIM -f -u NONE -c 'so $VIMRUNTIME/tutor/tutor.vim'

# Start vim without any .vimrc, set 'nocompatible'
$VIM -f -u NONE -c "set nocp" $TUTORCOPY
```

Comment: That's weird. The vimtutor script is behaving as though the quotes have been removed from the last few commands. `E471` means error number 471, not an error at line 471. You can find a little more about it with `:help E471`, assuming the help files in your installation work. Look at the last two commands in the vimtutor script. If there were no quotes in `-c "so $VIMRUNTIME/tutor/tutor.vim"`, vim would try to execute the `:so` command without an argument, which would give you E471, and would try to open a file named `$VIMRUNTIME/tutor/tutor.vim`, which it can't find, probably because...

Comment: ... $VIMRUNTIME is being expanded by the shell instead of by vim and is empty. If there were no quotes in the next command, `-c "set nocp" `would be interpreted as the command `:set`, which would output the `--- Options ---` stuff, then try to open a file named `nocp`. The `1 more file to edit` is due to vim thinking it has two file arguments, `nocp` and `$TUTORCOPY`. That's what seems to be happening, but I can't tell you why.

Comment: @garyjohn - thanks for your input. I should have realised that E471 was Error 471 - Doh! I have edited my question to include the last few lines of my vimtutor script. FWIW I tried manually launching `vim -f -u NONE -c 'so $VIMRUNTIME/tutor/tutor.vim'` and get a different albeit similar error (in vim): `"$VIMRUNTIME/tutor/tutor.vim" [New DIRECTORY]
Error detected while processing command line:
E471: Argument required`

Comment: Whilst you didn't explicitly resolve the issue for me, you gave me enough info to discover the issue! I discovered that I had a `/usr/local/bin/vim` script. I don't recall it's purpose but it seems that was the culprit. The script was calling vim like this: `/usr/bin/vim $@`. I assume that would be the cause of the shell expanding $VIMRUNTIME.  I removed that and now it works! Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 2):

As noted as a comment, the problem was that I had a `/usr/local/bin/vim` script which was calling vim without quoting the arguments. So as pointed out by @garyjohn the bash expanded `$VIMRUNTIME` would have been empty.

Random local vim script removed and all is now well.